# Transform Load pipeline for a logs system: Apache Airflow or Kafka Connect?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, architecture, airflow, apache-kafka-connect

### **Introduction:**

Actually, I've build and manage a solution of industrial network inventory:

Data sources => ETL jobs (Python) orchestrated by Apache AirFlow  => OpenSearch => Dashboard

---

My second job is to implement a log centralizator system:

Hosts(log agents) => **Ingest pipeline** => Kafka => **Transform Pipeline** => OpenSearch

*Logs: system, app & network.*

*Expected target: 15000 Hosts.*

The ingest & transform pipeline could be done with logstash or other parsers.

---

**Requirement of the ingest & transform pipeline:**

**Must:**

Manageable/monitor

Scalable

Resilent

SecurityByDefault

**Should:**

Use the same tech bricks as much as possible to descrease maintenability cost.

---

First solution: Using Apache Airflow to orchestrate and manage the Ingest and Transform pipelines.

**Question:**

Can Airflow process that much I/O logs activity?

Can Airflow scale up to reach the final load (15K hosts)?

Second Solution:

If Airflow is not made for that huge I/O pipeline (logs system), I planned to use Kafka Connect instead (new system block => more maintenance cost).

Note: I wish to avoid discution about maintenance cost because it depend of the sector, teams...

Comment: Is there any particular reason why did you not list [`logstash`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/just-enough-kafka-for-the-elastic-stack-part1)?